# Código mal formatado é escondido

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, formatação

Vários usuário inexperientes simplesmente colam o código na pergunta e ao submeter parte do código some.

Hoje mesmo ao entrar em uma pergunta só havia o texto descritivo sobre a dúvida e o código totalmente em branco, após 2 comentários pedindo ao AP adicionar o código, me veio a sugestão de edição e sim, o código estava lá, bastava uma simples formatação.

[link da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263707/label-concatenando-resultados-subsequentes-como-limpar-o-resultado-anterior)

Não acho interessante a ideia de que em toda pergunta sem código devêssemos edita-la para ver se realmente o código está lá, não seria melhor algum aviso de a pergunta não foi processada corretamente para que pudéssemos edita-la rapidamente?

Comment: Poderia postar um link para a pergunta?

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta, mas foi editada mais de uma vez, então acho que não será possível ver a formatação original.

Comment: Todas as edições feitas na pergunta são persistidas.

Comment: Bom saber, não costumo olhar esses detalhes...

Comment: O dificil é um identificador ter certeza que aquilo ocorreu por falha ou não da marcação, iria gerar muitos invalidos que na verdade seriam válidos.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para deixar o código visível.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu acho que se existe marcação de código, mas o código não está visível, é certo que o código está lá e está mal formatado.

Eu acho que a intenção de ajudar um usuário novato, editar suas perguntas e guiá-lo no uso do site é nobre, louvável e comendável. O sistema foi construído para isso - há incentivos para edição (pontos, medalhas) por esse motivo.

Eu concordo com o sentimento de ajudar o novato, mas acho que cada usuário do site tem seus limites. Código extremamente formatado é um dos meus limites. Quando um usuário tem apenas algum problema de indentação, eu edito... Mas quando:

- todo o código está em apenas uma linha, ou...
- quando falta código, ou...
- o código não é um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável...

... Eu uso as duas ferramentas que o sistema tem para lidar com essa situação.

- **Voto negativo:** o texto de ajuda do voto negativo diz, e eu cito com ênfases:

> Esta pergunta não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa; **ela não é clara** ou não é útil

- **Voto para fechar:** pelo exato mesmo motivo. O texto do motivo diz:

> **Não está clara o suficiente**
>   **Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes** para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, **é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando**. Consulte a página Como perguntar para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.

No caso da pergunta específica, vi [seu histórico de edições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/263707/revisions) e [o conteúdo bruto do primeiro post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/47c2b0eb-a490-45c6-912a-1ec6a01a2c05/view-source), que é o seguinte, sem nada adicionar ou remover:

> Tenho 2 label que recebem os resultados de uma conta feita dentro do código( calculadora de gasto de lampadas) quando clico em calcular ele calcula e printa o resultado no label, se eu clicar em calcular denovo ele concatena os resultados, como limpar o primeiro resultado?

Não se trata de código mal formatado, se trata de código ausente mesmo. Mais uma vez, é nobre ajudar um usuário nesse caso, mas não se espante se ver uma pergunta dessas fechada rapidamente dada a falta de esforço na criação da pergunta.

Comment: Legal sua opinião, então foi eu que equivoquei? pelo que vi no histórico o primeiro estado da pergunta esta só a descrição, depois veio a sugestão de edição de código de um usuário chamado 'analise sen' aprovada por mim e @dvd, o que eu poderia pensar, já que vi anteriormente códigos parcialmente ocultos no site por má formatação? kk, enfim só queria ajudar msm.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte acho que você não está equivocado. A partir de uma certa pontuação, as atualizações em post podem acontecer sem precisar de uma recarga de página. Pode ter acontecido isso em algum momento.

Comment: Já agora, @FelipeDuarte, o sistema bloqueia a publicação da pergunta em alguns casos, se detectar código por formatar.